How to execute a function if a loop is taking a long time?
I have an AJAX call, and the result is processed by a callback. This may be real quick, or take some time. If the callback lasts more than 3 seconds, I want to display an image (or a text) that tell the user "please wait!".
This is what I have:
var process_timer, is_processing = false;
var request = createCORSRequest();
if (request) {
    // This SETTIMEOUT function should execute 3 seconds after REQUEST.SEND()
    process_timer = setTimeout(function(){
        if (is_processing) {
            // It's still processing, so we show the message
            show_please_wait();
        }
    },3000);
    request.onload = function() {
        process(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
        // OK, processing is done, so we reset everything
        is_processing = false;
        // If SETTIMEOUT didn't fire yet, we cancel it so no image will ever show
        clearTimeout(process_timer);
        // We hide the message anyway, just in case it was displayed
        hide_please_wait();
    };
    is_processing = true;
    request.send();
}


What is happening:

REQUEST.SEND() works fine
REQUEST.ONLOAD() works fine
... but the SHOW_PLEASE_WAIT() function never gets executed, no matter how long the process lasts.
What am I doing wrong?


Have you tried debugging?  Such as removing the conditional from the setTimeout to see if show_please_wait ever fires? You could also log it's value in the setTimeout

It also seems like tracking isProcessing is a bit superfluous in this function.  You really only need to clear the timeout and hide_please_wait.   When onLoad runs either the please wait is showing or it's not and both states will be cleaned up with clearTimeout & hide_please_wait

the code you posted works fine

Seems like this needs more info - are createCORSRequest, process, or request.responseText synchronous or async (as fetch is Promise-based, and so are responses)? If any are Promises they're missing await or then, so this would be the expected behavior and it succeeding seems like timing-luck-based.

@ScottZ Oh, you're right!...

@JaromandaX Thank you for the fiddle. Yes, it actually works the way it is in the fiddle... but it seems to me that the catch is actually in process(). When it is some simple thing, like a timeout, it works. But this function actually does a lot of processing, and that's where things hang: the setTimeout() won't execute until the end... And I want it to execute during execution of process(), if this function takes more than some seconds to complete.

in that case, it's process() that is your issue - consider using a "web worker"

@l3l_aze createCORSRequest() and process() are both synchronous. The AJAX call is asynchronous, obviously, so request.responseText is processed in the callback.

Using global variables for keeping the status of promises is problematic. Especially, when there can be more than one asynchronous process to wait for.
The following demonstrates how you can show the #waitDiv div conditionally after a minimum waiting time of 2000 ms.
The asynchronous function delayedFetch() simulates a fetch() that is (optionally) delayed by a waiting time (ms). It handles the display of the specified div  element (here:#waitDiv) internally, without using any global variables.


const waitDiv=document.getElementById("wait");
async function delayedFetch(url,div,ms) {
  console.log("show waiting message div after 2000ms");
  const timeout=setTimeout(()=>div.classList.remove("hidden"),2000);
  // call this function without the parameter ms or
  // remove the following line in your "real" application:
  if (ms) await new Promise(r=> setTimeout(r,ms)).then(()=>console.log(`extra delay of ${ms}ms is over`));
  const data=await fetch(url).then(r=>r.json());
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  div.classList.add("hidden");
  return data;
}

delayedFetch("https://dummyjson.com/users/2",waitDiv,5000).then(u=>
 console.log(`all done, user name is: ${u.firstName} ${u.lastName}`)
)
.hidden {display:none}
<div id="wait" class="hidden">please wait ... this is taking longer!</div>



You can, of course, also do it with XMLHttpRequest() and also without async and other ES5/6 features:


function show(o){console.log("The response was: "+o.firstName+" "+o.lastName)}
function delayedFetch(url,div,ms,fn){
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url );
  xhr.responseType="json";
  setTimeout(function(){xhr.send()},ms);
  const timeout=setTimeout(function(){div.classList.remove("hidden")},2000)
  xhr.onload = function() {
   if (xhr.status != 200) {
    alert("Error "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
   } else {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    div.classList.add("hidden")
    fn(xhr.response);
   }
  };
}

delayedFetch("https://dummyjson.com/users/2", document.getElementById("waitDiv"),5000,show);
.hidden {display:none}
<div id="waitDiv" class="hidden">It seems to take a little longer ...</div>




Thank you for the great answer! This should be the way to go. The only catch is that I've had a bad time dwelling with async / await on older browsers, like IExplorer. What would you suggest as an answer that would work on those too?

I remember those days very well. It was a major headache getting things to work on all conceivable browsers. But the Internet Explorer is definitely dead. Do you really expect any of your users to be using a browser that does not support ES5/ES6 features?

I now also added a "legacy" version of getting the data with XMLHttpRequest(). Please, çheck out the new snippet.
